# How to break out of loop when URL read is taking too long

Tags: python-3.x, timedelay

Hi I have the following code to skip the particular URL if it is taking too long to read.

```
timeout = 30 
loop begins below for different urlz {

    timeout_start = time.time()

    
    webpage = urlopen(urlz[i]).read()
        
    if time.time() > timeout_start + timeout:
        continue}
```

My question is; wont the program execute the line of code "webpage = urlopen(urlz[i]).read()" before moving down to check the if condition? In that case I think it wont detect if the page is taking too long (more than 30 seconds to read). I basically want to skip this URL and move on to the next one if the program is stuck for 30 seconds (i.e. we have run into a problem when reading this particular URL).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `urlopen()` function has a timeout method inbuilt:

```
urllib.request.urlopen(url, data=None, [timeout, ]*, cafile=None, capath=None, cadefault=False, context=None)
```

So in your code:

```
timeout = 30 
loop begins below for different urlz {

    try:
        webpage = urlopen(urlz[i], timeout=timeout).read()
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to I skip the rest of the code below it, i.e. if it times out, I want to progress on to a continue statement to skip the code below it.

Comment: Oh I just remembered about exception handling lol.